# Windows XP環境で再生デバイスの音量を取得、操作する方法を知りたい

Tags: c#

お世話になります。
C#で下記のことを行いたいのですが、WindowsAPI等で可能でしょうか。

- デフォルトの再生デバイスのマスターボリュームの取得および設定
- デフォルトの再生デバイスのミュート状態の取得および設定

とりあえず、WindowsVista以降の方法はわかったのですが、WindowsXPで実装する方法がわからずにいます。
何かアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: わずかな情報ですが、ここからたどれるかも。[How to set sound volume programmatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2010/01/13/how-to-set-sound-volume-programmatically/)

Comment: VC++6の例 [mixerSetControlDetails](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4754/mixerSetControlDetails) と、商用SDKで、XP対応と書いてありますが、最新版ではサポート外になっているかも。[Sound Volume SDK ActiveX 4.0](http://www.viscomsoft.com/products/soundvolume)

Comment: C#での記事があったので紹介しておきます。[Changing master volume level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/294292/9014308), [How to set volume in C# and Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33169982/9014308)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

全般的な説明は[About Audio Mixers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Multimedia/about-audio-mixers)から辿れます。ただし、ここから辿れるAPIリファレンスはリンクが壊れているため、[Windows Multimedia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/_multimedia/)を参照することをお勧めします。また[Audio Mixers in Windows Vista](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Multimedia/audio-mixers-in-windows-vista)を参照するとわかりますが、XP以前向けの機能はVista以降の新APIとマッピングされているため、正しく作ればそのままVista以降でも動作します。

「デフォルトの再生デバイス」とありますが、Vista以降と異なり、XP以前ではどのアプリがどのラインに出力し、どのスピーカーにつながっているか等と把握できないため、結局のところデバイスID 0に出力するしかない状況です。

基本的な操作方法としては

1. `mixerOpen`で適切なミキサーを開く（`uMxId`はおおよそ`0`でいいです）
2. `mixerGetLineInfo`でラインを取得する
3. `mixerGetLineControls`でラインのボリュームコントロールやミュートコントロールを取得する
4. `mixerGetControlDetails`で各コントロールの現在値を取得したり、`mixerSetControlDetails`で値を更新したりする
5. `mixerClose`でミキサーを閉じる

という手順になります。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。英語はあまり得意のではないのですが、頑張って翻訳しながら試してみます。ありがとうございました。